# Waiting for elements to update in an asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, vba, excel

I am using excel vba to create an API of sorts for a third party `.aspx` site.
For testing I have set it up to search for a person by their ID and the print their name as displayed on the webpage.

The problem is that the function will print the name of the last person searched not the current one, even though the page displays the correct name.
So,

- search John Cleese's ID

  - Print "Cleese, John"
- search Michael Palin's ID

  - Print "Cleese, John"
- search Eric Idle's ID

  - Print "Palin, Michael"
- search Terry Jones' ID

  - Print "Idle, Eric"

I believe the cause is that the function is getting the name before the specific html element with the persons name on it has updated.  `.Busy` or `.ReadyState` seem ineffective because the site is ASP.NET

**Code**

```
Public Function search(ID as string)
    With IE
        .Navigate idSearch_URL                                      
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop          ' wait
        With .Document
            .getElementByID(idSearchTxt_ID).Vlaue = ID              ' enter id
            .getEleentById(idFindBtn_ID).Click                      ' search it
        End With
        Do While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Loop          ' wait
        Debug.Print .Document.getElementByID(nameLabelID).innerText  ' Prints prev. name
    End With
End Function
```

I know the issue is that the wait loops aren't waiting for existing elements to update because, if I set through with the debugger or just insert a `Sleep` call before the `Debug.Print`, then the correct name is printed.  What methods can I use to wait until the `nameLabelID` has updated or all of the webpage has updated.

I don't want to use a `Sleep` call because it's a waste of time and I can't shorten it to like 10 ms because I don't know if that would be long enough.

I don't think I should share much of the source code for the website. However, I could drop some of the javascript functions, if a solution involves them.

PS. I know nothing about ASP.NET.  The behavior of the site indicates like there are some local variables set when navigating the site.  Are they client side? Is there a way to grab those directly and bypass reading the webpage?

PPS, This may be just for comments, but would another language like perl or ruby be more appropriate for this than VBA?

Comment: How to approach this depends on exactly how the search is run: if the page isn't being reposted but the search occurs via (eg) AJAX then you can't use `ReadyState` to check whether the result has arrived. What you'd use instead really depends on how the page is structured.

Comment: So I must trace back the Javascript on the site and find out what function updates the label or retrieves the information from the server?  Assuming I find that out how do I know when that function has been called and has returned a value.  Also the site does use AJAX.

Comment: If you know the value of the element you're pulling the value from then you can wait until that value changes as a result of submitting a new search.